# center progress bar description

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am looking for a way to have an always centered progress bar description.
I have a progress bar in the header of a panel to inform users about the panel-content.

**The problem: the description is always on the left side of the progress bar (success part).**
[image]

**What i want is that the description is always in the center of the bar, something like this:**
[image]

**Please see my attempt below:**

```css
.inline .in {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.panel .inline .progress {
    top: 7px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}

.panel .progress {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-heading-btn {
    float: right;
}

.panel-title {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.panel-heading {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Panel Heading</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-heading-btn">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-success" data-click="panel-reload"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-warning" data-click="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-danger" data-click="panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="inline">
        <h4>Panel Heading</h4>

        <div class="progress in">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success used_progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="32.14" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
        50 / 100 available                          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="progress in">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success used_progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="32.14" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%">
        10 / 100 available                          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="progress in">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success used_progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="32.14" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
        90 / 100 available                          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is something independent of the whole progress bar construction. The floats, the widths.

One way to do this is put the description in an element of its own and position it absolutely.

```css
.inline .in {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.panel .inline .progress {
  top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  background-color: red;
}

.panel .progress {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.panel-heading-btn {
  float: right;
}

.panel-title {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.progress-description {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Panel Heading</h2>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-heading-btn">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-success" data-click="panel-reload"><i class="fa fa-repeat"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-warning" data-click="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-danger" data-click="panel-remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="inline">
        <h4>Panel Heading</h4>

        <div class="progress in">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success used_progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="32.14" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
            <span class="progress-description">50 / 100 available</span> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="progress in">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success used_progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="32.14" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%">
            <span class="progress-description">10 / 100 available</span> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="progress in">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success used_progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="32.14" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
            <span class="progress-description">90 / 100 available</span> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```